# Time-out occurred while waiting for buffer latch type 3 while processing MOLAP cube

Tags: sql-server-2012, timeout, ssas, olap-cube

This is the error I get from the Log while trying to process a SQL Server 2012 MOLAP Cube.

*"Time-out occurred while waiting for buffer latch type 3 for page (1:2044928) database ID 2.; 42000." Source="Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Analysis Services" HelpFile="Error ErrorCode="3240034318" Description="Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while processing the 'Measurement' partition of the  measure group for the 'PE cube' cube from the Cube database."*

I have scripted the processing task in XMLA and execute the processing via a SSAS Command in an Agent Job.
The first step is to Process Update all dimensions and this succeeds, but when I want to Process Data of the cube the load fails and this error pops up.

I first tried processing with an SSIS package, but this caused the whole server to crash instead of just the job failing. This leads me to believe this a performance issue, but the machine running the job is an Azure VM with 16 processors and 112 GB RAM so I don't know where to look. I also tried running the job without any other activities on the server, but that did not help.
The disk containing the SSAS Instance still has 500GB Free.
The measure group is querying a table containing 180 million records.

While processing the cube on a Dev server with way less data there are no issues. I once succeeded to Process Full the whole cube while processing the SSAS cube directly within SSAS, but via DTEXEC, SSISDB or using SSDT the processing results in a server crash.
Earlier I got different time-out errors, but after adjusting the SSAS ExternalCommandTimeOut, ExternalConnectionTimeOut and ForceCommitTimeout properties to 0 this did not occur anymore.

I have tried multiple processing settings, but because I think it is a performance issue I tried to make the processing as low as possible on performance.

**Processing Settings:**
**Object:** Cube; **Option:** Process Data;
**Processing Order:** Sequential with Seperate Transactions. 
**Writeback Table Option:** Use Existing;
Do not process affected objects.

**Update:**
I have processed the measure which triggered the error on its own, this did not finish and in the Activity Monitor I saw a lot of Wait_Type IO_Completion and CXPacket. And when querying the sys.dm_exe_requests I see a Select with wait_type IO_Completion which is already running for a long time and a lot of reads.
Last night I tried to process all measurements excluding the measuregroup which triggered the error earlier, but unfortunately the whole server crashed again...

**Update2:**
We have looked into upgrading to premium storage, but this means we have to switch from A11 to a DS or GS serie. Meaning we need to resize the whole VM which contains live solutions resulting in down-time and effort to restore the VHDS and replacing the current OS disk which contains parts of live solutions.
Another option we identified is applying partitioning or improving the underlying queries from the measures. Unfortunately way more effort than anticipated, a quick work-around for now would help a lot in selling a long-term solution improvement.

**Update3:**
We have had contact with Microsoft and they advice to migrate from an A11 VM to a D14 V2 and upgrade to premium storage disks. This will be our next step and will be executed upcoming friday. After the migration I will update or close this post.

If you miss information, please let me know. Any suggestions that would help me pin-point the situation would be much appreciated!

Comment: That buffer latch timeout looks like an error within your relational SQL database. Focus your time there

Comment: Can you monitor available RAM on the server during processing? I'm worried that you will see available RAM shrink to zero during processing but that is just a guess. If that's what's happening let us know and we can discuss appropriate memory limits for SQL and SSAS that should help. If not we will look elsewhere.

Comment: Hi Greg, thank you for your response. I have allocated 60GB of the 112GB RAM to SQL Server, during the processing msmdsrv.exe (SSAS) uses around 2-5 GB. The RAM is most of the time in between 60-80% used. I have also tried processing when there were no other activities and then there was around 40% free RAM. .

Comment: sounds like you need to focus on the IO layer of SQL. Where are the data files for SQL. Standard storage? Premium storage? How many disks in the storage pool?

Comment: The datafiles for SSAS and the Datamart are located on the disk with 500GB Free, the disk is Standard storage with GPT partition. There are no related Storage Pools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upgrade to a VM better suitable for the situation (DS14 V2) and upgrade to P30 premium storage disks have resolved the occuring issues. The issue was not in the way the cube was being processed or configured, but in the hardware used.